# tf.expand_dims error in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm beginner in tensorflow and i want to implement **CNN** in my code on images 
but i get an error in a line which i don't understand why

**This is the main code**

```
Batch_size = 128
Batch_indx = 1
Batch_GreyImages = []
Batch_ColorImages = []
imgsize = 224, 224 
channels = 1  
def ReadNextBatch(): 
    global Batch_GreyImages
    Batch_GreyImages = []
    global Batch_indx
    for ind in range(Batch_size):
        Colored_img = Image.open(r'path')
        Batch_ColorImages.append(Colored_img)
       #============================================================
        Grey_img = Image.open(r'path')
        Grey_img = np.asanyarray(Grey_img) 
        img_shape = Grey_img.shape
        img_reshaped = Grey_img.reshape(img_shape[0],img_shape[1], channels)#[224,224,1]
        Batch_GreyImages.append(img_reshaped)#[#imgs,224,224,1]
        Batch_indx = Batch_indx + 1
    return Batch_GreyImages


Input_images = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,224,224,1])

def RunAll():
    #region low level
    low_level_network = Network()
    # 1st conv layer with 64 kernels 3X3, 1 channel, stride 2
    layer = Layer(Input_images,1,3,3,64,2,'Relu')
    print(layer.h_conv)
    low_level_network.layers.append(layer)

    # 2nd conv layer with 128 kernels 3X3, 64 channel, stride 1
    layer = Layer(low_level_network.layers[0].h_conv,64,3,3,128,1,'Relu')
    print(layer.h_conv)
    low_level_network.layers.append(layer)

    # 3rd conv layer with 128 kernels 3X3, 128 channel, stride 2
    layer = Layer(low_level_network.layers[1].h_conv,128,3,3,128,2,'Relu')
    print(layer.h_conv)
    low_level_network.layers.append(layer)

    # 4th conv layer with 256 kernels 3X3, 128 channel, stride 1
    layer = Layer(low_level_network.layers[2].h_conv,128,3,3,256,1,'Relu')
    print(layer.h_conv)
    low_level_network.layers.append(layer)

    # 5th conv layer with 256 kernels 3X3, 256 channel, stride 2
    layer = Layer(low_level_network.layers[3].h_conv,256,3,3,256,2,'Relu')
    print(layer.h_conv)
    low_level_network.layers.append(layer)

    # 6th conv layer with 512 kernels 3X3 , 256 channel, stride 1
    layer = Layer(low_level_network.layers[4].h_conv,256,3,3,512,1,'Relu')
    print(layer.h_conv)
    low_level_network.layers.append(layer)
    #endregion

    #region mid level

    mid_level_network = Network()
    # 1st conv layer with 512 kernel 3x3, 512 channel, stride 1
    layer = Layer(low_level_network.layers[5].h_conv,512,3,3,512,1,'Relu')
    print(layer.h_conv)
    mid_level_network.layers.append(layer)

    # 2nd conv layer with 256 kernel 3x3, 512 channel, stride 1
    layer = Layer(mid_level_network.layers[0].h_conv,512,3,3,256,1,'Relu')
    #layer_mid = layer
    print(layer.h_conv)
    mid_level_network.layers.append(layer)
    #endregion

    #region global level

    Global_level_network = Network()

    # 1st conv layer with 512 kernels 3X3 and 512 channel, stride 2
    layer = Layer(low_level_network.layers[5].h_conv,512,3,3,512,2,'Relu')
    print(layer.h_conv)
    Global_level_network.layers.append(layer)

    # 2nd conv layer with 512 kernels 3X3 and 512 channel, stride 1
    layer = Layer(Global_level_network.layers[0].h_conv,512,3,3,512,1,'Relu')
    print(layer.h_conv)
    Global_level_network.layers.append(layer)

    # 3rd conv layer with 512 kernels 3X3 and 512 channel, stride 2
    layer = Layer(Global_level_network.layers[1].h_conv,512,3,3,512,2,'Relu')
    print(layer.h_conv)
    Global_level_network.layers.append(layer)

    # 4th conv layer with 512 kernels 3X3 and 512 channel, stride 1
    layer = Layer(Global_level_network.layers[2].h_conv,512,3,3,512,1,'Relu')
    print(layer.h_conv)
    Global_level_network.layers.append(layer)
        #endregion
    #region MultiLayerOfGlobal
    ML_Net = ML(Global_level_network.layers[3].h_conv,3,[1024,512,256])
    print("MLP OutPut Tensor : ", ML_Net.ML_OUTPUT)
    print()
    #endregion
       #-------------------------------------------
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    Prediction = RunAll()
```

And **Class Layer**

```
    def weight_variable(shape):# Intialize random weights for num of kernels of specific shape
        initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
        return tf.Variable(initial)

    def bias_variable(shape):
        initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
        return tf.Variable(initial)

    def Conv2d(inp, W ,Stride):# Get conv2d layer with input,filter num,strid,padd

        return tf.nn.conv2d(inp, W, strides=[1, Stride ,Stride, 1], padding='SAME')

    class Layer:
        def __init__(self, inp,inp_channels_num,filter_width_size,filter_height_size,outp_channels_num,stride,activation_func):
            self.W_conv = weight_variable([filter_width_size, filter_height_size, inp_channels_num, outp_channels_num])
            self.b_conv = bias_variable([outp_channels_num])    
            if (activation_func=='Sigmoid'):
                self.h_conv = tf.nn.sigmoid(Conv2d(inp, self.W_conv, stride) + self.b_conv)
            else:
                self.h_conv = tf.nn.relu(Conv2d(inp, self.W_conv, stride) + self.b_conv)


        def UpSampling(self,Nsize_x,Nsize_y):
            self.h_conv = tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(self.h_conv,[Nsize_x,Nsize_y])
```

And **class MLP**

```
class ML():
    ML_OUTPUT = None
    input_for_classification = None
    def __init__(self, input_tensor, layers_count, node_for_each_layer):
        FeatureVector = np.array(input_tensor)
        FeatureVector = FeatureVector.flatten()
        self._init_model(FeatureVector, layers_count, node_for_each_layer)

def _init_model(self, FeatureVector, layers_count, node_for_each_layer):

    hidden_layer = []
        Alloutputs = []

        hidden_layer.append({'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FeatureVector.shape[0], node_for_each_layer[0]])),'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_for_each_layer[0]]))})
        for i in range(1, layers_count):
            hidden_layer.append({'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_for_each_layer[i - 1], node_for_each_layer[i]])),'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_for_each_layer[i]]))})

        FeatureVector = tf.expand_dims(FeatureVector,0)
```

this code gives me Error

> Expected binary or unicode string, got

In this line

```
FeatureVector = tf.expand_dims(FeatureVector,0)
```

however i didn't use ine **sess.run** yet so i expect it to run this operation when run **Run_all()** with session so why gives me this error what is wrong or am i missing?

Comment: Why it run the Error line without using sess.run??

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace or a smaller example with the same error? It's a lot of code to read through to see what calls what to determine what exactly is FeatureVector.